# Getting the inlining failed warning during gcc compilation

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, warnings, inline

What is the reason for the following kind of warning

```
     inlining failed to while calling the function: The code size may grow.
```

when function is static inline.Following is a kind of function defined in header file. How can i get rid of the above mentioned warning.

```
        static __inline___ getSomething(){
        return something;
        }
```

EDIT

yes i tried removing the `inline`, but i get the following warning

```
     function getSomething defined but not used.
```

Is there any way to remove both the warnings?

[EDIT]

```
  -g -Wno-unused  -g -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings
```

Comment: I suppose this is gcc complaining; are you using any compile time optimization flags as well?

Comment: saw your edit; you can safely remove the function declaration and code then :)

Comment: yes i did remove it. Still program runs successfully. Is it like due to the function not been used?

Comment: @adirau yes i am using optmization flags. I will edit it in the problem.

Comment: seems so. anyway I am curious as of what compile options are you using and what's the exact function that makes gcc complaining

Comment: @adirau, i added the warning and flags.I clearly see the calling of the function that i deleted in other source file.Ya, the  program gets compiled but i am not so sure whether its functionality is ok because i don't have the test case to check if the code where the function gets called is executed.Incase if it used then what can be the best possible approach to get rid of those warning?

Comment: if the compiler tells you that the function isn't used you should trust that. even if you see the function being called in some other source file, the compiler saw better that no such conditions will ever be met for the function to really get called

Comment: anyway, I couldnt reproduce the warnings, using your compiler options and a simple static __inline__ function with just a return, never used, just declared, gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5), x86_64

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `__inline__` keyword. Compilers are generally smart enough to know when to inline, and unless you're doing detailed profiling and know better, trying to force it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Is the function really not used? may be it should be removed altogether?